# Termux ssh connection over usb-c result in connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh, tcp, usb-c, adb, termux

I got an Oneplus 8 with Kali NetHunter.
I want to ssh to Termux and I can, but only if the device connect to my LAN **at least once**.
If I restart the phone and I jump the connection with WiFi/internet and try to connect to ssh the connection fails resulting in "kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host"
I try to connect from Windows using private key (the pub key is already in the sshd service).

To sum up:

```bash
adb devices
# List of devices attached
# device1          device

adb forward tcp:8022 tcp:8022

adb forward --list
# device1 tcp:8022 tcp:8022

nmap.exe localhost
# 8022/tcp  open  oa-system

ssh.exe -vvv -i C:\Users\username\.ssh\privkey -p 8022 localhost
# OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
# debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/config
# debug1: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/config line 3: Applying options for localhost
# debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
# debug2: resolving "localhost" port 8022
# debug2: ssh_connect_direct
# debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 8022.
# debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10061, io:0000022562F48690
# debug1: connect to address ::1 port 8022: Connection refused
# debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 8022.
# debug1: Connection established.
# debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username\\.ssh\\privkey type 3
# debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/privkey-cert error:2
# debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/privkey-cert.pub error:2
# debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username\\.ssh\\privkey-cert type -1
# debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/privkey type 3
# debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/privkey-cert error:2
# debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/privkey-cert.pub error:2
# debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/privkey-cert type -1
# debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
# kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

But if I connect to my WiFi with my smartphone and retry to ssh:

```bash
ssh.exe -vvv -i C:\Users\samuele.plescia\.ssh\ags-key -p 8022 localhost
# OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
# debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/config
# debug1: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/config line 3: Applying options for localhost
# debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
# debug2: resolving "localhost" port 8022
# debug2: ssh_connect_direct
# debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 8022.
# debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10061, io:000001DFE3F49870
# debug1: connect to address ::1 port 8022: Connection refused
# debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 8022.
# debug1: Connection established.
# debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username\\.ssh\\privkey type 3
# debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/privkey-cert error:2
# debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/privkey-cert.pub error:2
# debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username\\.ssh\\privkey-cert type -1
# debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/privkey type 3
# debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/privkey-cert error:2
# debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/privkey-cert.pub error:2
# debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/privkey-cert type -1
# debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
# debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.3
# debug1: match: OpenSSH_9.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
# debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
# debug1: Authenticating to localhost:8022 as 'blabla'
```

Connection will succeed.

Seems that the connection always go through 127.0.0.1 as I'd like and want.

The thing is that now I can disconnect without problem and ssh will still work.

How can I bypass the initial connection to LAN?

Is this a problem of termux's openssh implementation?

## EDIT 1:

I found a strange solution, I just setted the password with `passwd` in termux:

```bash
passwd
pkill sshd
sshd
```

Until now I had **ONLY** public key auth to log into ssh and didn't work.
After setting the password I can connect with pub key.

```bash
$> adb logcat -s 'sshd:*'
--------- beginning of main
05-08 09:37:37.232 26232 26232 I sshd    : Server listening on :: port 8022.
05-08 09:37:37.232 26232 26232 I sshd    : Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 8022.
05-08 09:37:41.901 26234 26234 I sshd    : Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 49765
05-08 09:40:46.758 26278 26278 I sshd    : Accepted publickey for ags from 127.0.0.1 port 56537 ssh2: ED25519 SHA256:blablabla
```

Then I just setted `/usr/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to have `PasswordAuthentication no` and it's working.